# WCF - Get associated ServiceContract in ServiceAuthorizationManager

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, service, authorization

I am attempting to implement a custom ServiceAuthorizationManager. On my ServiceContract I have a custom attribute on each method called 'Authorization' where I have a flag if authorization is required or not.

What I want to do is from within my ServiceAuthorizationManager to get the associated ServiceContract for the current request, check the attribute for the endpoint being hit, then just return true if authorization is not required.

What is the best way to get access to this? Once I get it, I can easily use reflection to get my authorization information.

Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well one way is to get the action like this:

```
string action = operationContext.RequestContext.RequestMessage.Headers.Action;
```

The action is in the format:

```
ServiceNamespace/ContractName/OperationName
```

If you plan to use reflection to get the interface and check it custom attributes, that should be all you need.

Comment: Thanks, this should work. I was hoping for something simpler, but I will take what I can get.